# My java code works properly in linux but not on Windows

Tags: java, linux, swing, windows-8, calculator

I am making a Calculator using Java Swing and I am having a bit of a problem. When on linux (linux mint 14 nadia) my calculator works properly but when used in Windows 8 it opens correctly but says there is a problem when parse-ing my input String to double number.

```
private double convertToNumber(String n) {
    //Double dbl = new Double(n);  
    //return dbl;
    return Double.parseDouble(n);
}
```

I tried the part I commented out too but that does not work either.

The error message says that the line `return Double.parseDouble(n);` is creating the problem but why is this not a problem in linux?

I will let a little bit of code that I think may be causing the problem follow:

```
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##########"); //Instance variable

//Use: x.getTotalString
//Post: getTotalString is the final product (end result)
public String getTotalString(){
formattedValue = numberFormat.format(total);
formattedValue = formattedValue.replaceAll("^-(?=0(.0*)?$)", "");
return "" + Double.parseDouble(formattedValue);
//return "" + Double.parseDouble(numberFormat.format(total));
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the "problem" under Windows 8? Different versions of Java? A compile error (what's the exact message)? A runtime error? Or simply incorrect runtime behavior?

Comment: "The error message says that the line "return Double.parseDouble(n);" is creating the problem." So...... what's the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably comes from a different `Locale` in your environments.

In your Windows environment, the `String` you parse may not be in the format you specify: `#.##########`. Try to print the number you are trying to parse and check that the format you use is the right one.

Comment: The problem was that in Winows I had to use "," instead of "." before the decimal places but somehow it does not matter in linux.

Comment: Yes that is what I suspected :)